# Unable to drop default constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS MODIFY AGE INT DEFAULT 10;
```

Table altered.

```
SQL > ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS ALTER COLUMN AGE DROP DEFAULT;

ERROR at line 2:
ORA - 01735 : invalid ALTER TABLE OPTION.
```

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `drop default`

Comment: Since when is the default value for a column a CONSTRAINT?

Answer (score 13):

Your `ALTER` statement is wrong and you cannot use two `ALTER` commands in one statement. And we never drop default value instead we set it to `NULL`.

> If a column has a default value, then you can use the DEFAULT clause to change the default to NULL, but you cannot remove the default value completely. If a column has ever had a default value assigned to it, then the DATA_DEFAULT column of the USER_TAB_COLUMNS data dictionary view will always display either a default value or NULL.

[ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm)

Use the following SQL command to drop the default.

```
ALTER TABLE constomers MODIFY age DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: But according to the below link we can drop the default constraint. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_default.asp

Comment: As you have seen practically and I have pointed to the Oracle official documentation, this doesn't work for Oracle.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: @MasudShaik: w3schools is known to be full of errors. You should rely on the manual, not some random findings on the internet if you want to get the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

Use `MODIFY [COL_NAME] DEFAULT NULL` instead of `ALTER COLUMN [COL_NAME] DROP DEFAULT` so far oracle does not accept the latter version.